# Where are the 2 by 2 turntables in LDD?

Tags: ldd

I just updated to LDD to 4.3.9 today and I can't find the 2 by 2 turntable pieces. What section are they under now?

Comment: Can you use LDD's search?  Then again, it can be difficult to know what exact name they are called, but turntable sounds about right.

Comment: @Gliderman I tried that but only the 4 by 4 turntables came up that is why I asked here.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find them in the hinge parts category (next to minifig one) under the name "Turn Plate 2x2", number 3679 / 3680. [Brickset](http://brickset.com/parts/design-3680) uses LEGO names for parts, this can help finding them in LDD

Answer (score 2):

I agree with **SMS von der Tann**... I'd upgrade LDD to 4.3.9 and the turn plates 2x2 ARE NOT in any category anymore (I seek it everywhere more than twice). My solution was to save a 2x2 turn plate, from another LDD model I made before upgrading, to the templates and then re-use it when I need.

Regards

Comment: Yeah, I personally copy-pasted it from other models.

Answer (score 2):

If you temporary change your theme to the extended LDD, the turntables are still in the hinge section, this way you can paste them into your build and color them, after that you can change back to the normal theme of LDD